# Как организовать событие в событии?

Tags: jquery

Задача такая:

Пользователь нажимает на кнопку:

```
jQuery('.button').on('click', function() {
    $this = jQuery(this);
    ... // Получаем кое какие данные из data
    ... // Открываем модальное окно
    return false;
});
```

Далее у нас открывается модальное окно с формой. Пользователь вводит данные и отправляет форму. 
Получается что-то такое:

```
jQuery('.button').on('click', function() {
    $this = jQuery(this);
    ... // Получаем кое какие данные из data
    ... // Открываем модальное окно

    jQuery('.send').on('click', function() {
        $this = jQuery(this);

         // Вот тут должны быть данные те что были получены выше

         return false;
    });

    return false;
});
```

Все это работает, но по какой-то причине события по нажатию кнопки с формы срабатывают несколько раз. 
Если несколько раз открыть-закрыть бутстрап окно, то 2 событие будет выполняться несколько раз, каждый раз + 1.

Подскажите, как с этим делом разобраться?

Answer (score 1):

Ну так, сколько раз нажимаешь `.button` — столько раз устанавливается очередной обработчик события `jQuery('.send').on('click', function() {...})`.

Нужно либо устанавливать обработчик события на `.send` извне (один раз), либо, если так уж важна экономия, то нужно снимать «предыдущий» обработчик:

```
function sendOnClick() {
    $this = jQuery(this);

     // Вот тут должны быть данные те что были получены выше

     return false;
}

...
jQuery('.send').off('click', sendOnClick);
jQuery('.send').on('click', sendOnClick);
...
```

Это если грубо.